# No SB_LINEDOWN when scrollbar position is zero

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-2008

Scrollbar isn't giving SB_LINEDOWN or SB_PAGEDOWN events when the current position is at the top.  If I drag the thumb down, then events are delivered.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is the range of your scrollbar set properly? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527.aspx

Comment: I get the expected values from GetScrollRange.  If I drag the thumb down a little, then SB_LINEDOWN, etc work as expected.  If I run the position to the top via either the thumb or the up-arrow, I don't get any more SB_LINEDOWN events until I drag down the thumb.

Comment: One possibly interesting thing is that the scrollbar was created implicitly in CWnd::Create using WS_VSCROLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not expectedly it was a logic problem caused by incorrectly using the pos argument to OnVScroll. (facepalm)  Thanks and a +1 to Mark Ransom for taking the time to reply.